# How can I get the gradle default start script?

Tags: gradle

We want to modify the app start script in our distribution.  We believe this created by substituting variable values into a template.  The default result is perfectly fine for us except we want to add some lines in the middle.

If we could get a copy of the template and modify it then we could use that, but we do not know where to find the template.

Any and all clues gratefully received.

EDIT:
All my knowledge of this comes from:
[Customizing start script generation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/application_plugin.html#sec:customizing_start_script_generation)
and
[CreateStartScripts](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.jvm.application.tasks.CreateStartScripts.html)
Which between them tells me everything I need to know except where to get a copy of the default start script template that I can modify.
/EDIT

Thanks in advance

Comment: never tried this myself so I won't write a full answer, but customizing the script generation seems possible, see https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/application_plugin.html#sec:customizing_start_script_generation

Comment: Thanks @M.Riccuiti.  I *had* read those, but was remiss in not including the reference.  Both that page you mentioned and the link from it are the sources of my entire knowledge on the subject.
I will amend my question to include the links.